# "Bicubic Graphs related to Riemann Surfaces"-Census

Tags: graph-theory, riemann-surfaces, bipartite-graphs

I'm currently collecting ways how to relate bicubic graphs on orientable surrfaces with Riemann Surfaces.
So far I got the following:

- Grothendieck's [Dessin D'Enfants](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2709419/19341)
- Makover's [Approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1626800/19341)
- Hurwitz's [Way](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3034043/19341)
- Nieser's [Method](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2047672/19341)
- a relation to [knots](https://mathoverflow.net/q/275112/11856)

> What other constructions to relate bicubic graphs with Riemann Surfaces are known?

Any idea with reference welcome...